# cypher create a node that is a relationship to a relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i.e a comoment; so the node points directly to the relationship not other nodes.;  I tried this in cypher :

CREATE (comment1:comment { Name : "Comment1" ,commentorder:1})-[ax:commentto { Name : "Comment to" }]->(VerseofParshah}

where VerseofParshah is a relationship; won't accept it
l;

Invalid input '}': expected an identifier character, node labels, a property map or ')' (line 1, column 112 (offset: 111))
"CREATE (comment1:comment { Name : "Comment1" ,commentorder:1})-[ax:commentto { Name : "Comment to" }]->(Genesis}"

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Neo4j. Relationships only connect to nodes. There may be other models (hypergraphs?) in which relationships can point to relationships, but there are few graph dbs out there which do this.

If you use a node instead of a relationship, you can often get the effect you want, but it does require some adjusting of your model.

Comment: This is required when more information is needed for a relationship than what can be done in an attribute;
  ie comments and comments on comments about the relationship that are specific to the relationship   
 Mindmapping software allows this and it is often a beginning part of the process of graph modeling.   
 Workaround: split the relationship into 2 parts; create a dummy 
 node and point your new node  to the dummy node
connecting the 2 parts.  .thanks for responding marty.